# Multiple Products with same name in Google Play's IAB

Tags: android, in-app-billing, ab-testing, abtest

I'm trying to create multiple products in Google-play's developer console that will have the same name/description to the end user (but different sku's) for purchases in my Android app.

The goal is to perform A/B style testing with various price points so I can tune the pricing of products...

Ex.

```
Description        sku    price
My Cool Product    p.a    $4.99
My Cool Product    p.b    $5.99
My Cool Product    p.c    $6.99
```

Where my users are broken into different test groups each group seeing a different product (so each group just see's 'My Cool Product' but depending on their group gets a different price).

Google's IAB is indicating 'The title in English (United States) (en_US) is already used by 'p.a'.

Since A/B testing is such a mainstay of running a site, does anyone have a work around to allow proper A/B testing?